# Email HTML - line not able to line break properly with _ instead of -

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, formatting

I've spent hours researching this and I'm trying to edit an email where they would like the References to say something like:

1. American Parkinson Association: https://www.test.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/12-09.com
2. ABCDEF: https://www.test.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/1234567890_098765_4321.com

However, when I code the 2nd numbered list, because there are underscores in the link and not dashes, it instead turns to the below with the link on it's own separate line. If I change the underscores to dashes, it will work formatting wise, but the link is obviously incorrect. I tried adding a "space" in the text of the link but if someone has to copy the link and send it, it will contain the "%20" and error out. If I add a "br" in the text, I will have to link both sections of the link. If I force the link to span across, then the whole width of the email will stretch and look weird.

2. ABCDEF: 
   https://www.test.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/1234567890_098765_4321.com

This is driving me crazy. There has to be an easier way. Please help?

Comment: Any update on this issue? What'd you move forward with? If my answer was of any help, then kindly consider accepting the answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, since it was going to a small group of people - they wanted to keep the link text hyperlinked so it was extremely long. The reason for this is so they could provide a reference to a scientific peer reviewed reference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's because the entirety of the line itself may be too long, and thus making the line jump down. It should not be because of underscores specifically, or any of that sort.

You have quite a few options.

1) Add CSS that formats the text and/or links to a size where the link is within the acceptable size that you desire. There are numerous ways to achieve this.

2) Simply make an anchor tag that links to your desired url, and you can type whatever seems the most reasonable as the visual link.

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.test.com/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/1234567890_098765_4321.com">Whatever text you want</a>
```

The second solution is more clean, and that way you can make it way more compact and straight to the point as well. Having ridiculously long links in an E-mail looks unprofessional in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A few follow-up to your comments. When I change the underscore to a dash, it looks exactly as it should and line breaks on it's own at the - towards the end of the link and the rest goes onto a new line (without be having to add a "br"). It's really strange how it doesn't work with an underscore which is why I mentioned it. 
 For your option 1: Does that mean it will decrease the dont so it all fits?  2: The business wants the linked text to be the same as the link (I tried). :)

Comment: Thing with HTML E-mails is that you should already feel pretty handcuffed in terms of what you can do since you're not allowed to use JavaScript etc. Most companies I've dealt with are open to suggestions, especially if you can deliver your arguments in a reasonable manner.

Comment: If you can't reasonably argue with the company, then you'll be stuck with having to minimize the font or something that will allow the text to stay on a singular line if you don't want the break. And even then, it still matters what device width we're talking about as well, so if you want absolutely 0 breaks across all platforms / screen widths, it'll become weirdly small. I highly suggest you put up some valid arguments for why the anchor tag solution is the better call.